# Can DNS leak happen in a VPN connection when accessing a page by its IP address?

Tags: dns, vpn

Say that you are using another channel (for example another laptop) and using the `dig <hostname>` command or other online methods you managed to get the IP address of a website, `www.example.com`.

Now, in your primary laptop that is connected to an arbitrary VPN, you can access `www.example.com` using the IP address found above.

My question is if this eliminates the possibility of a DNS leak.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, yes. If you access example.com via the IP address DNS would never be touched.

However,

If example.com also hosts example.org, it might use the hostname to determine which site to serve. In this case it will see the IP address as a different site entirely. which may give unexpected results.

You can fix this problem by adding example.com to your hosts file.

Also, if example.com has a link to images.example.com, then your machine will perform a lookup on that address, which could potentially leak.

To solve this, you would need to disable DNS resolution.

Of course if you're not using HTTP(S) then all of these are less of a problem.